# Русификация валидации формы YII 2

Tags: php, yii2

Доброго времени суток.
начинаю осваивать yii 2 но проблема с руссификацией валидайии формы вот SiteControler

```
 use app\models\EntryForm;
  public function actionEntry()
    {
        $model=new EntryForm();
        f($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&&$model->validate()){
            return $this->render('entry-confirm',[model=>$model]);
        }else{
            return $this->render('entry',['model'=>$model]);
       }
    }
```

это кусок кода 
вот модель EntryForm

```
 namespace app\models;
    use yii\base\Model;

    class EntryForm extends Model
    {
        public $name;
        public $email;
        public function  rules()
        {
            return[
                [['name','email'],'required'],
                ['email','email','message'=>'Некоректный e-mail адрес'],
            ];
        }
    }
```

это view entry

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
$form=ActiveForm::begin();?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')?>
<?= $form->field($model,'email')?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Oтправить',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

подскажите в чем ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте!

Первое: выставите локализацию в конфигах.
common\config\main.php

```
<?php
return [
    'language' => 'ru-RU',
    'sourceLanguage' => 'ru-RU',
    'timeZone' => 'Europe/Moscow', //опционально, играет роль для каждого конкретного проекта
    .................
];
```

Второе: если перевод сообщения отсутствует или не устраивает, добавьте валидатору свойство message (что Вы и сделали). Если сообщение не отображается, проверьте кодировку Вашей модели - возможно, она отличается от UTF-8.

Comment: это basic не advansed но насчет utf-8 вы оказались прав спасибо. А что это так важно. ответ я вам поставлю влюбом случае.

Comment: Это очень важно. Работая с современными веб-скриптами, следите, чтобы кодировка файлов всегда была UTF-8 (могут быть исключения, но они сейчас очень редки). Если есть возможность, сделайте настройку, чтобы редактор открывал ANSI как UTF-8 (Notepad++, например, это может)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
return [
    'language' => 'ru-RU',
    'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US', // !!! Базовый язык лудше оставить англисским
    'timeZone' => 'Europe/Moscow',
];
```